# Writing from a custom type to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been stuck for a few days now on this. I can get my albums to write to the console but I can't figure out how to get them to write into an array. The code works so when I click "Show Albums" button, it returns nothing other than [Object, object]. Can anyone help me figure out how to write the new albums to the array so it displays properly? Thanks in advance.

```
(function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var year = document.getElementById("year");
    var showbutton = document.getElementById("showlist");
    var submitbutton = document.getElementById("submit");
    var validate = document.getElementById("validate");
    var albumlist = [];

    var albums = function album(name, year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.album = function() {
            return ((this.name + ", " + this.year));
        };
    }

    albums.prototype.genre = "rock";

    var album1 = new albums("album1", "1999");
    var album2 = new albums("album2", "2000");
    var album3 = new albums("album3", "2001");
    var album4 = new albums("album4", "2002");
    var album5 = new albums("album5", "2003");
    albumlist.push(album1, album2, album3, album4, album5);

    showbutton.onclick = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < albumlist.length; i++) {
            console.log(albumlist[i]);
        }
        document.getElementById("myalbums").innerHTML = albumlist.sort() + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Your () and {} don't seem to match up.  Is this all of your code?  Is there also html?

Comment: You can't set an entire array to innerhtml. You need to loop over it and access each individual index like you do for the console log. And when you do you need to also use specific property values. Setting an array to innerhtml just calls toString behind the scenes which is why you see [object object].

Comment: Thanks Atheist, that is something I did not think about. Basically I should eliminate the console.log and then move my next line of code up there? Sorry, I'm struggling with this section a lot and can't seem to figure out the transition from writing a custom type to an array.

Comment: Yes and then access property values like albumlist[i].name.

Comment: One last question on this, how would I get it to display the name and year like it shows in the console.log? I also can't seem to get the list to break out in the HTML.

Comment: The way it displays in the console is the browser doing special things for debug purposes. You will need to access specific values using dot notation like I did in previous comment. Not sure what you mean by break the list out. Can you explain more and maybe I can help.

Comment: I want the list to display like this:

album 1, 1999 -> Return to next line:
album 2, 2000. I used the <br/> tag but that didn't seem to take effect.

Comment: The break tag will work but you need to use it inside the for loop. Not just once when you set innerhtml. Append break tag on each loop iteration.

Comment: How would I go about that? I've never put an html tag in a for loop before

Comment: Just like you were doing it outside the loop. Just use string concatenation. Using the answer below as an example: names += albumlist[i].name + '<br/>';

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I can't get my .sort() function to work now. I have tried placing it in the innerHTML area, but it says names.sort() is not a function. Also sorry, I would DM but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @awhitaker Give me a little bit. Had a birthday party for friends kid today. Then I'll give a hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("myalbums").innerHTML = albumlist.sort() + "<br/>";
```

Take a look at what this line does. This takes an array, which is an object with many functions, keys, etc, and tries to plot in on the page.

It will not be possible, since javascript doesn't know how to turn that array into a string.

For you to do that, you have to first create the string you want and than plot it on the page.

You need to iterate through the items and generate a string, for example:

```
var names = "";
for(var i = 0; i < albumlist.length; i++){
  names += albumlist[i].name + ' ';
}
```

and then replace it on the html:

```
document.getElementById("myalbums").innerHTML = names + "<br/>";
```

Comment: It works fine in the console log which is great, but I want it to display on an HTML page. I guess I should have specified that, sorry.

Comment: I have edit my answer to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: JavaScript does know how to turn that array into a string it's just not the string he is looking for technically.

Comment: I also get an undefined display, I tried changing the names += to see if that would change anything and it does not. thoughts?

Comment: It's because the names string is not initialized in the code above. var names = ""

Comment: I forgot to initialise the variable names. it should be stated `var names = ''`